# laravel auth middleware is not redirecting to login page

Tags: laravel, authentication, middleware

I am having some trouble with the auth middleware. I had put the middleware to a route group and I rolled back my users table. I expected the app to redirect me to my login/singup page but instead it didn't do that and it just gave me "Trying to get property of non-object" which refers to a `Auth::user()` function in my dashboard view (which I shouldn't have access to).

here's my route code:

```
 Route::group(['prefix' => '/{username}/', 'middleware' => ['existing_user', 'auth']], function(){ 
     Route::get('/dashboard', function(){
         return view('dashboard');
     });
 });
```

Here's my view:

```
<h1>{{ Auth::user()->username }}</h1>
```

Also, I wasn't sure if deleting the users from the database means that Laravel will automatically delete the user session.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: The user session should be deleted by clearing your browser's cookies for your domain (say localhost)... Since, the session is still valid for laravel and it is unable to find that user anymore in the database, auth()->user() is now null and that is why you are getting the **Trying to get a property of a non-object** error....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The users session can be deleted by clearing your browser's cache for your domain (say localhost).

Laravel uses the **Auth class** for keeping track of sessions. And since sessions work at both *Client* And *Server Side*, a session must be deleted from either of the places. Removal at Client side is through Browser's cookies and removal at client side can be either via File, Database or Redis etc...

So, removing users from **Users table** makes no sense in this case. Deleting the user from the database will not help the Auth class know that there is no session anymore. Infact `auth()->user()` becomes `null` and `auth()->check()` still gives `true`.

Hope this cleared your concepts a little :)